# Error: Layer invocation in the presence of activity regularizer(s) is not supported yet

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm using `tf.loadLayersModel()` to load into [tf.js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js) and get this error:

```
Error: Layer invocation in the presence of activity regularizer(s) is not supported yet.
```

I am using an L2 regularizer and to ensure it works properly I am also including this:

```
class L2 {

  static className = 'L2';

  constructor(config) {
     return tf.regularizers.l2(config)
  }
}
tf.serialization.registerClass(L2);
```

What is the issue?

**NOTE:** This is a Tensorflow model being moved to Tf.js, but Tf.js supports activity regularizers.

### UPDATE:

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-layers/src/engine/topology.ts) is the source code for the unimplemented error. So is it not possible to load a Keras model with regularizers?

Comment: What happens if you use `tf.regularizers.l1l2` instead?

Comment: Same result @edkeveked

Comment: Can you please share your model and the version of tfjs used ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on the message, and [the link to the repo you provided](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-layers/src/engine/topology.ts)

I looked at my **python code** and commented  `activity_regularizer` parameters in `tf.keras.layers.Dense()` and it seems to work after generation with `tensorflowjs_converter` (at least javascript doesn't show errors).

```
 model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        # ...
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu',
                              kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal(),
                              # activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(1e-04) --> 
                              # ^ Comment line above because not working on tensorflow.js
        # ...
    ])
```